# loop through dataframe columns to do simple linear regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")

for column in df:

    X = df["Row Labels"]

    Y = df[column]
    y1 =Y.values.reshape(-1,1)
    x1 =X.values.reshape(-1,1)
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(x1, y1)
    y_new = []
    y_i = []
    for i in range(12,24):
        y_new.append(regressor.predict([[i]]))
        y_i.append(i)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column':y_new})
```

i write this code to loop through the dataframe columns to do simple linear regression and put all the predicted value in dataframe. but it is predicting only the last columns value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column':y_new})` creates a column named `'column'` verbatim (not the name saved in the variable `column`. Moreover, `df2` is recreated in every iteration, each iteration it only saves the last `y_new`.

I think what you want is to create a new column in `df2` in each iteration:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for column in df:

    X = df["Row Labels"]

    Y = df[column]
    y1 =Y.values.reshape(-1,1)
    x1 =X.values.reshape(-1,1)
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(x1, y1)
    y_new = []
    y_i = []
    for i in range(12,24):
        y_new.append(regressor.predict([[i]]))
        y_i.append(i)

    df2[column] = y_new
```